# Magento 2 - How to know which .less file I have to change and what I have to change

Tags: magento2, css, less

I want to change the background color of a certain button in the customer area.
It is the "Compare Product" Button at the left sidebar.

How do I know which .less file I have to change?

[image]

The selector is **.actions-toolbar .primary**

```
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <a data-bind="attr: {'href': compareProducts().listUrl}" class="action compare primary" href="foo"><span>Vergleichen</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="secondary">
        <a id="compare-clear-all" href="#" class="action clear" data-post="bar">
            <span>Alles löschen</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Normally I would just override `styles-l.css` or `styles-m.css` and make my change. But I've read that these files are generated by .less files, so this would be stupid.

Comment: No need to change existing files or find source code, just add your custom CSS and override!

Comment: @Pawan, where do I have to add my custom CSS? And do I need to use .less or .css?

Comment: I only used CSS, I can give you solution for that!

Comment: The question is about less though...

Answer (score 1):

You can use _buttons.less file to change color of button. You can simply override this file in your theme if not exists. Below is the path

```
app/design/frontend/[VENDOR]/[THEME]/web/css/source/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enable sourcemaps your browser's dev tools will tell you which source file the styling is being applied from.

You'll need to make sure you're using [Grunt](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/tools/using_grunt.html?itm_source=devdocs&itm_medium=search_page&itm_campaign=federated_search&itm_term=grunt) to compile and you have enabled [sourcemaps](https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/336c4982194bcb02ef8a) in your browser.